# How to change customer account page layout 2columns-left to 3columns in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I have added below code in `VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`.

Also tried changing in VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

But none of these are working.

What could be the issue?

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: Have u Cleared cache?

Comment: yup i definitely did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml` replace the below line:

```
layout="2columns-left"
```

to the:

```
layout="3columns"
```

Run the Below Command : `php bin/magento cache:flush & php bin/magento cache:clean` & then Try

Answer (score 1):

Try to use customer_account_index.xml in your module for reference

VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Add your code as  added below.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remove the cache and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to just override the xml file for example
```

customer_account_login.xml file to your theme customer layout.

File path for making customer login page 2columns-left,

app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_lgoin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override customer_account.xml
Place the `<page>` tag and change the layout to 3 column layout.

layout="3columns"

Magento Doc Link:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Cust
omer/layout/customer_account.xml

Note:I have tried customer_account_index.xml & customer_account.xml
But Except Account Information remain all the pages are changed to 3 columns.